# Graph of a function - asymptotes properties

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

Is it possible that the graph of a function has vertical asymptote if $D_{f} = \mathbb{R}$?

Also, is it possible that the graph of a function intersects its asymptote? (horizontal, slant or vertical)

The answer to both questions seems a straight-forward **NO** to me, but can someone help prove that? Thanks!

Comment: Consider the function: f(x)= 1/x if x is not 0, f(0)= 1.  That function has a vertical asymptote at x= 0 but is defined for x= 0.

Comment: How can f(x) = 1/x be defined for x = 0, if x=/=0, hence domain D = R\{0}? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I did not say anything at all about f(x)= 1/x.  Go back and read my post again.

Comment: I understand now. But since y = 1 for x = 0, how can there be an asymptote then?

Comment: What is your **definition** of "asymptote"?

Comment: To make it as simple as I can: I guess an asymptote is a line that never touches a graph of a function. In this case vertical asymptote x = 0 would 'touch' the point at f(0), that is f(0) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is *continuous* on $\mathbb{R},$ then doesn't have a vertical asymptote. If $f$ is not continuous, it can happen what explained in comments.

It is not possible that a graph of a *function* cuts its vertical asymptote. That would contradict the definition of the function.

For the second part, a quote from Wikipedia:

> Asymptote of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as one or both of the x or y coordinates tends to infinity.

The *distance* between the courbe and the asymptote (horizontal or oblique/slant) has to tend to $0$ with $x\to\infty,$ intersections are allowed.
 As an example, consider $$f(x)=\frac x2 + \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}.$$ Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(f(x)-\frac x2 \right)=0,$ the line $y=\frac x2$ is an asymptote of the graph of $f$ (see figure). However, they cut, even infinitely times.

[image]